# Two separate keyboards, two separate spacebars

Tags: macros, keyboard, autohotkey, hid, remap

Basically I've used 2 keyboards for a very long time for the sake of personal convenience, but now there's something that's really bugging me. I'd like to remap the spacebar on my second keyboard to w/e so that I can play a particular game with two separate space bars.

Problems I've encountered so far is that keyboard remapping software tend to remap the keys for both keyboards. Or the remaping doesn't work in-game although it seems to work fine in notepad or such. Mostly likely since the remapping occurs on a higher level then where the game is fetching it's inputs.

Here's what did on HIDmacros;

For the trigger kbd6 32 ()

```
HIDMacros.SendKeys "p"
```

Not much but I'm not too savvy in this field haha

Does anyone know how I may achieve this?

-Edit: Oh and the ability to "hold" the key is a must, or else they'd be no point in doing this :/. I'm thinking hardware modifications at this point haha

Comment: Upvote because that sounds like an interesting problem I'd like to know about, too, bur am too lazy to research. You'd porbably need some code to identify all keyboards, too.

Comment: Do a search for AHKHID.  It is a library that can differentiate USB HID devices.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use AutoHotKey AHKHID script and SharpKeys to accomplish something similar.

Using SharpKeys I remapped the key (in your case it's spacebar) to some fictitious key.
Then using AutoHotKey with AHKHID script, I was able to listen to strokes on that key, and determine from which device it was sent -
Then I would simulate the wanted key stroke.
I believe this could work in your situation (also, I simulate the up and down strokes, so "holding" works).

I've posted the full solution on the AutoHotKey's forum:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-of-the-hid-functions/page-29#entry631055

Good luck

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.